# What's the currently most endorsed/supported web build script engine for Visual Studio 2017 / Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017, build-script

After reading [this article](https://blog.knowhere.to/build-scripts-mit-npm-sind-grunt-gulp-und-bower-obsolet-27e39c747fe4) ([English translation here](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?act=url&depth=1&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.de&sl=de&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=https://blog.knowhere.to/build-scripts-mit-npm-sind-grunt-gulp-und-bower-obsolet-27e39c747fe4%3Fgi%3D838a66918ff2&usg=ALkJrhhvbEQiJXFVesj6zhk3d7yJn7eQiA)) I wonder what's the current situation for using web build script engines in Visual Studio Code.

What's the currently most endorsed/supported web build script engine for Visual Studio Code?

Is there a blog article available, written by the VS Code team?

Answer (score 0):

So far I know, VSCode does not recommend any specific build script engine and supports all. You can find the details in the vscode docs- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_task-autodetection